# Runtime error on installing Sqlite using the default Shellntel / luckystrike script on Win 10x64

Tags: sqlite

Trying to install [Shellntel/luckystrike](https://github.com/Shellntel/luckystrike/issues/23) on Windows 10 x64 box.
I 'm getting the following error:

```
### LUCKYSTRIKE INSTALLATION ROUTINE ###
[*] Installing\Importing Dependencies..
[*] Creating C:\work\luckystrike
[*] Downloading db.sql
[*] Creating & initializing database: C:\work\luckystrike\ls.db
Invoke-SqliteQuery : Unable to find type [DBNullScrubber].
At line:70 char:9
+         Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $dbConnection -Query $in ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DBNullScrubber:TypeName) [Invoke-SqliteQuery], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Invoke-SqliteQuery
```

Trying to get help on `Invoke-SqliteQuery : Unable to find type [DBNullScrubber]` on Google, found... very few tips??!! :(
Do I miss something obvious?
Does anyone faced such problem?